# Get height of different Elements and add different Classes

Tags: jquery

i have multiple H4's. I want the Height of each Element, that is working. After that, the smaller Height become the class "small" and the bigger one becomes the class "big". But this ist not working, both elements get both classes. Does somebody has any idea?

```js
 $(".box-services-c h4").each(function () {
  var getHeightHfour = $(this).height();
  console.log(getHeightHfour);

  var smallHeight = 18;
  var bigHeight = 36;

  if(getHeightHfour == smallHeight) {
   $(".box-services-c h4").addClass('small')
  }
    if(getHeightHfour == bigHeight) {
   $(".box-services-c h4").addClass('big')
  }
  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-services-c">
<h4>SPANNAX®<br>Spannfutter</h4>
</div>
<div class="box-services-c">
<h4>Spannfutter</h4>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tqg6zt5h/1/

Comment: sorry, wrong fiddle link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $(this) to refer to matched element inside each function:

```
if(getHeightHfour == smallHeight) {
   $(this).addClass('small')
}
if(getHeightHfour == bigHeight) {
   $(this).addClass('big')
}
```